# About relative/absolute CSS properties

Tags: css, css-position

I don't know why that `<div>` goes outside `<html>` tag...

I am currently learning CSS position thing. For my practice, I've tried to draw abstract painting on browser. But the leg-part `<div class='anpan-leg'>` somehow goes outside even `<html>` element.

here's my attempting in codepen. Any advice please?

https://codepen.io/yosukeino/pen/yLBXWxr

Answer (score 0):

You should know that relative is positioned relative to the normal position.The anpanman and anpan-head you set are the same height. anpan-body and anpan-leg's place will be squeezed out. anpan-body is set to relative positioning, but its original placeholder will not disappear. So anpan-leg will be displayed at that location.

Comment: Thank you very much for commenting. As you say, I should know relative property things. I've solved the mess, and I think I will learn more about it.

Big thanks!!